# Where would Ansible run a command if no directory is specified?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am encountering a problem where I am running the same tasks on 2 remote nodes and the directories that those commands are executed at are different.

If I run `pwd` through Ansible on each remote host before this command, they return different paths. For example `/usr` and `/usr/src`. If I log into the remote host manually I go to `/usr/src` for both (As specified in their configuration files).

Can anyone explain to me why is this happening? To what directory does Ansible go if you run a command without specifying a `chdir`?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this difference to happen because, when login in manually, you have a `.bashrc` that `cd` you in the right folder in one of those two hosts, when Ansible does not source the `.bashrc` file.

Per default, ssh, and, so, Ansible, logs you into the `$HOME` folder of the user you define Ansible to connect with, which you can also find in `/etc/passwd`

Another reason I could see for this to happen would be because you use one user to log into the node but then become another one.

inventory.yml

```
all:
  hosts:
    some.example.com:
      ansible_user: some_user
```

playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:

  - command: pwd # still you will be in /home/some_user
    become: yes
    become_user: some_other_user
```

Comment: " ~/.bash_profile is executed for login shells and ~/.bashrc is executed for interactive non-login shells. "   https://attack.mitre.org/techniques/T1156/ That would mean it is actually executing bashrc

Comment: No, neither one neither the other. Further reading: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29637#issuecomment-380672737. Remember that Ansible doesn’t do pure SSH, it uses a python module that connects you to your hosts (and that connection is even configurable). So your safer bet is either to set a the folder as home to your users, either to `chdir`, and the later is your safest bet.

Comment: And if I remember properly, per default, Ansible uses the paramiko plugin to connect https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection.html